How to use type/interface args as function parameter
Is it possible to use type/interface args as function a parameter ?
If not, is it because of typescript compiler ?
I have a type A
type A = {
  name: string;
  value: number;
}

And I want something like
const f = (keyof A) => {
   console.log(name)
}

will be transpilled to
const f = (name: string, value: string) => {
   console.log(name)
}

Edit for more context:
I am reworking a part of old code
I have a callback function that needs to return the values of the type passed
I know that I can do it by using this piece of code
const f = (args: A) => {
   console.log(args.name)
}

I was just thinking about the way explained above
And looking at why. (but the answer can be in the edit...)

I'am not at all sure what you are trying to achieve, but transpiling a function with one parameter to a function with two parameters will never happen. If you give more context, then we might be able to help you better.

You cannot, as an interface has no key order, whereas function parameters are ordered. Unless you introduce extra assumptions to impose an order. There is very probably already a detailed post.

What do you mean? You can always define this function as const f = ({ name, value }: A) => { ... }. I am guessing that's what you are asking for

That being said, as probably implied by Lehks's comment, it is perfectly valid to keep a single parameter that is an object of your given type; this gives named parameters in JS/TS. But that may not fit what you absolutely want.

Function parameters are not bindable by name and object properties are not ordered. What you are trying to do  doesn't make sense.
